# Java command execution failed

Tags: java

Hey if anyone can figure out why my code isn't working that would be greate. Every time i try to run either as file or as project it fails. I don't really know what to do to try and fix this i am quite new so if it is something basic that i overlooked sorry. I am running netbeans 11.2 in case that matters.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.gameclock;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.accessibility.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
/**
 *
 * @author jacobk
 */
public class GameClock001 extends JFrame {

    private final JLayeredPane layeredpane;
    private JLabel background;

    private JLabel monthdot;
    private JLabel daydot;
    private JLabel hourdot;
    private JLabel mindot;
    private JLabel ampmdot;

    private JLabel monthbuttons;
    private JLabel daybuttons;
    private JLabel hourbuttons;
    private JLabel minbuttons;
    private JLabel ampmam;
    private JLabel ampmpm;

    private JButton monthup;
    private JButton monthdown;
    private JButton dayup;
    private JButton daydown;
    private JButton hourup;
    private JButton hourdown;
    private JButton minup;
    private JButton mindown;
    private JButton ampm;


    public GameClock001() {

        super("Game Clock");
        setSize(900, 603);
        setLookAndFeel();
        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
        setLayout(flo);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ImageIcon Background = new ImageIcon("GameClockSmol.jpeg", "GameClockIMG");
        ImageIcon up = new ImageIcon("Up.jpeg", "Button Up");
        ImageIcon down = new ImageIcon("Down.jpeg", "Button Down");
        ImageIcon dot = new ImageIcon("dot_png29.png", "Dot");
        ImageIcon swap = new ImageIcon("switch.png", "Switch");
        layeredpane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 563));

        int monthx = (0);
        int monthy = (0);
        int dayx = (0);
        int dayy = (0);
        int hourx = (0);
        int houry = (0);
        int minx = (0);
        int miny = (0);

        background.setIcon(Background);
        background.setBounds(0, 0, Background.getIconWidth(), Background.getIconHeight());
        monthdot.setIcon(dot);
        monthdot.setBounds(monthx, monthy, dot.getIconWidth(), dot.getIconHeight());
        daydot.setIcon(dot);
        daydot.setBounds(dayx, dayy, dot.getIconWidth(), dot.getIconHeight());
        hourdot.setIcon(dot);
        hourdot.setBounds(hourx, houry, dot.getIconWidth(), dot.getIconHeight());
        mindot.setIcon(dot);
        mindot.setBounds(minx, miny, dot.getIconWidth(), dot.getIconHeight());
        ampmdot.setIcon(dot);


        monthbuttons.setText("Month");
        daybuttons.setText("Day");
        hourbuttons.setText("Hour");
        minbuttons.setText("Minute");
        ampmam.setText("AM");
        ampmpm.setText("PM");



        monthup.setIcon(up);
        monthdown.setIcon(down);
        dayup.setIcon(up);
        daydown.setIcon(down);
        hourup.setIcon(up);
        hourdown.setIcon(down);
        minup.setIcon(up);
        mindown.setIcon(down);
        ampm.setIcon(swap);


    layeredpane.add(background, new Integer(3));

    layeredpane.add(monthdot, new Integer(1));
    layeredpane.add(daydot, new Integer(1));
    layeredpane.add(hourdot, new Integer(1));
    layeredpane.add(mindot, new Integer(1));
    layeredpane.add(ampmdot, new Integer(1));

    add(monthbuttons);
    add(daybuttons);
    add(hourbuttons);
    add(minbuttons);
    add(ampmam);
    add(ampmpm);

    add(monthup);
    add(monthdown);
    add(dayup);
    add(daydown);
    add(hourup);
    add(hourdown);
    add(minup);
    add(mindown);
    add(ampm);
    add(layeredpane);   


    }
    private void setLookAndFeel() {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            // ignore error     
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        GameClock001 frame = new GameClock001();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, how does it fail? I note you never set your frame visible. And you're doing everything on the `main` thread.

Comment: And for example, `monthup` is never created - so `monthup.setIcon` most likely is failing.  More examples of that failure type in code as well.  You would need to do something like `monthup = new JButton("click");` first.

Answer (score 0):

The two things I notice immediately, you are doing everything on the `main` thread (which will terminate almost immediately) and you never set your frame visible. Change your `main()` method to something like,

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            GameClock001 frame = new GameClock001();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey i tried that and it builds properly but doesn't stay open or show me a window so now i am even more confused.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final JLayeredPane layeredpane;
private JLabel background = new JLabel();

private JLabel monthdot = new JLabel();
private JLabel daydot = new JLabel();
private JLabel hourdot = new JLabel();
private JLabel mindot = new JLabel();
private JLabel ampmdot = new JLabel();

private JLabel monthbuttons = new JLabel();
private JLabel daybuttons = new JLabel();
private JLabel hourbuttons = new JLabel();
private JLabel minbuttons = new JLabel();
private JLabel ampmam = new JLabel();
private JLabel ampmpm = new JLabel();

private JButton monthup = new JButton();
private JButton monthdown = new JButton();
private JButton dayup = new JButton();
private JButton daydown = new JButton();
private JButton hourup = new JButton();
private JButton hourdown = new JButton();
private JButton minup = new JButton();
private JButton mindown = new JButton();
private JButton ampm = new JButton();


public GameClock001() {

    super("Game Clock");
    setSize(900, 603);
    setLookAndFeel();
    FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();
    setLayout(flo);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ImageIcon Background = new ImageIcon();
    ImageIcon up = new ImageIcon("download.png", "Button Up");
    ImageIcon down = new ImageIcon("download.png", "Button Down");
    ImageIcon dot = new ImageIcon("download.png", "Dot");
    ImageIcon swap = new ImageIcon("download.png", "Switch");
    layeredpane = new JLayeredPane();
    layeredpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 563));

    int monthx = (0);
    int monthy = (0);
    int dayx = (0);
    int dayy = (0);
    int hourx = (0);
    int houry = (0);
    int minx = (0);
    int miny = (0);

    background.setIcon(Background);
    background.setBounds(0, 0, Background.getIconWidth(), Background.getIconHeight());
    monthdot.setIcon(dot);
    monthdot.setBounds(monthx, monthy, dot.getIconWidth(), dot.getIconHeight());
    daydot.setIcon(dot);
    daydot.setBounds(dayx, dayy, dot.getIconWidth(), dot.getIconHeight());
    hourdot.setIcon(dot);
    hourdot.setBounds(hourx, houry, dot.getIconWidth(), dot.getIconHeight());
    mindot.setIcon(dot);
    mindot.setBounds(minx, miny, dot.getIconWidth(), dot.getIconHeight());
    ampmdot.setIcon(dot);


    monthbuttons.setText("Month");
    daybuttons.setText("Day");
    hourbuttons.setText("Hour");
    minbuttons.setText("Minute");
    ampmam.setText("AM");
    ampmpm.setText("PM");



    monthup.setIcon(up);
    monthdown.setIcon(down);
    dayup.setIcon(up);
    daydown.setIcon(down);
    hourup.setIcon(up);
    hourdown.setIcon(down);
    minup.setIcon(up);
    mindown.setIcon(down);
    ampm.setIcon(swap);


layeredpane.add(background, new Integer(3));

layeredpane.add(monthdot, new Integer(1));
layeredpane.add(daydot, new Integer(1));
layeredpane.add(hourdot, new Integer(1));
layeredpane.add(mindot, new Integer(1));
layeredpane.add(ampmdot, new Integer(1));

add(monthbuttons);
add(daybuttons);
add(hourbuttons);
add(minbuttons);
add(ampmam);
add(ampmpm);

add(monthup);
add(monthdown);
add(dayup);
add(daydown);
add(hourup);
add(hourdown);
add(minup);
add(mindown);
add(ampm);
add(layeredpane);   


}
private void setLookAndFeel() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();   
    }
}
public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    GameClock001 frame = new GameClock001();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you would explain what you changed, and why, instead of just dumping a hundred or so lines of code and expecting readers to visually discern what you changed.